# how to append output of onesed command to another sed command

Tags: unix

I am having the following :

`sed -n '/* Query Data Source Name/,/$/p' < XTRWFRLS.txt > XTRWFRLS.out`

`sed -n '/* WHERE Clause/,/$/p' < XTRWFRLS.txt > XTRWFRLS.out`

While I run the first command its showing some output and while running the second command its overwriting the first output. How do I append the output of second command to output of first command?

Answer (score 1):

Use `>> XTRWFRLS.out` instead of `> XTRWFRLS.out` to append instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

sed -n '/* Query Data Source Name/,/$/p' < XTRWFRLS.txt > XTRWFRLS.out

sed -n '/* WHERE Clause/,/$/p' < XTRWFRLS.txt >> XTRWFRLS.out